# How to assign a validation group on specific form element in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a form class in Symfony2 and I am adding validation criteria to each element of the form (NOT to the connected entity object). I would like to add validation groups to some of the elements but I cannot seem to figure it out how.

I specify validation groups of the form like this:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\CommonBundle\Entity\Campaign',
        'validation_groups' => array('Default', 'new_title')
    ));
}
```

And on a specific form element I do this:

```
->add('title', 'text', array(
    'required' => true,
    'help_text' => 'This is the title.',
    'constraints' => array(new NotBlank(), new Length(array('min' => 3, 'max' => 150))),
    'validation_groups' => array('new_title')
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a validation group to a specific form element ([as described in the docs for current symfony2 version](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups)) like this:

```
->add('title', 'text', array(
'required' => true,
'help_text' => 'This is the title.',
'constraints' => array(new NotBlank(array('groups' => array('new_title')), new Length(array('min' => 3, 'max' => 150, 'groups' => array('new_title')))),
```